# Need faster PHP/MySQL search algorithm for highly complex calculations

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, algorithm

I have a dilemma that I'm trying to solve right now. I have a table called "generic_pricing" that has over a million rows. It looks like this....

[image]

I have a list of 25000 parts that I need to get generic_pricing data for. Some parts have a CLEI, some have a partNumber, and some have both. For each of the 25000 parts, I need to search the generic_pricing table to find all rows that match either clei or partNumber.

Making matters more difficult is that I have to do matches based on substring searches. For example, one of my parts may have a CLEI of "IDX100AB01", but I need the results of a query like....

```
SELECT * FROM generic_pricing WHERE clei LIKE 'IDX100AB%';
```

Currently, my lengthy PHP code for finding these matches is using the following logic is to loop through the 25000 items. For each item, I use the query above on clei. If found, I use that row for my calculations. If not, I execute a similar query on partNumber to try to find the matches.

As you can imagine, this is very time consuming. And this has to be done for about 10 other tables similar to generic_pricing to run all of the calculations. The system is now bogging down and timing out trying to crunch all of this data. So now I'm trying to find a better way.

One thought I have is to just query the database one time to get all rows, and then use loops to find matches. But for 25000 items each having to compare against over a million rows, that just seems like it would take even longer.

Another thought I have is to get 2 associative arrays of all of the generic_pricing data. i.e. one array of all rows indexed by clei, and another all indexed by partNumber. But since I am looking for substrings, that won't work.

I'm at a loss here for an efficient way to handle this task. Is there anything that I'm overlooking to simplify this?

Comment: Is restructuring the tables possible? Because it appears as though you never built in the proper references to effectively query the data you're looking for

Comment: I honestly don't know if it would be any better, but you might be able to do something like use a full text index and then do a [boolean search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) to find words starting with a specific string.

Comment: I added some additional indexes, and it sped up the process drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* query the db for all rows and sort them in your app. Will cause a lot more headaches.
Here are a few suggestions:

1. Use parameterized queries. This allows your db engine to compile the query once and use it multiple times. Otherwise it will have to optimize and compile the query each time.
2. Figure out a way to make `in` work. Instead of using like try `... left(clei,8) in ('IDX100AB','IDX100AC','IDX101AB'...)`
3. Do the calculations/math on the db side. Build a stored proc which takes a list of part/clei numbers and outputs the same list with the computed prices. You'll have a lot more control of execution and a lot less network overhead. If not a stored proc, build a view.
4. Paginate. If this data is being displayed somewhere, switch to processing in batches of 100 or less.
5. Build a cheat sheet. If speed is an issue try precomputing prices into a separate table nightly, include some partial clei/part numbers if needed. Then use the precomputed lookup table.